# How can I make a matrix average calculator in Scilab?

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, average, scilab

I want to make a non-overlapping 3D matrix in scilab, and loop through it with a cube of NxNxN size assigning the average value of the voxels in the cube to the center voxel.

Go to Page 2 to see exactly what I need.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5wCiQEnPJYZdGxCcmRBc0NHNGc/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you so much in advance.

P.S. Don't worry about the invalid averaging volume problem. The Matrix can just be 100x100x100 or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you describe is different from the paper you posted. I followed your description, but split it up into multiple lines so you can easily adapt it to your requirements.

It is very similar to [the MatLab answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19440875/1149326) somebody posted in your other question. I am not aware of anything similar to `mat2cell` and `cellfun` in SciLab as used in the other answer.

```
clear; clc

K = 100
N = 5

mid = floor(N/2)

volume = rand(K, K, K)
cubeCount = floor( K / N )

for x=0:cubeCount-1
    for y=0:cubeCount-1
        for z=0:cubeCount-1

            // Get a cube of NxNxN size  
            cube = volume((1:N)+N*x, (1:N)+N*y, (1:N)+N*z);

            //Calculate the average value of the voxels in the cube
            avg = sum( cube ) / (N * N * N);

            // Assign it to the center voxel
            volume( N*x+mid+1, N*y+mid+1, N*z+mid+1 ) = avg
        end
     end
 end

disp( volume )
```